# 'Follow the bouncing kernel' technique in kernel design

Tags: kernel, virtual-memory

Good evening. 
I'd like to know some details about the abovementioned technique. The main goal is to allow user applications to use full 4GB virtual memory space. For now every user application has a lot of readonly information about kernel datastructures in it's virtual memory layout.
Unfortunately Google didn't helped me much with 'Follow the bouncing kernel', so I'm curious if this technique has some commom name or what is it about?

Comment: Note that [this is a homework question](http://cs.ucla.edu./~kohler/class/06f-aos/lab2.html) for several computer science courses.

Comment: Indeed its a homework question, but I'm seeking for general information rather than particular answer.